# Large terraform pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, terraform

I'm working on building out Jenkins for our rather large and growing infra. Currently we use terraform with userdata to launch our instances into AWS. Our repo is currently set up with this hierarchy

```
terraform/
├── server1/
│   ├── server1.tf
│   ├── userdata.yaml
├── server2/
│   ├── server2.tf
│   ├── userdata.yaml
├── server3/
│   ├── server3.tf
│   ├── userdata.yaml
├── server4/
│   ├── server4.tf
│   ├── userdata.yaml
├── server5/
│   ├── server5.tf
│   ├── userdata.yaml
```

Ideally Jenkins would launch when we merge into master, however we want it to only run on the changed/new file to prevent deleting instances and trying to build 50+ servers. What would be the best way for Jenkins to check for changes through the folders and only apply the terraform pipeline to those new/updated?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Terraform already handles this with its state file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the approach in your way, but if you insist to do it via jenkins, you can write a wrapper to run the terraform depend on which files are changed.

```
folders=`$(git show --name-only |awk -F \/ '/^terraform/{print $1, FS, $2}')

for folder in ${folders}
do
  pushd ${folder}
  terraform init <options>
  terraform plan <options>
  terraform apply <options>
  popd
done
```

Comment: What would you suggest as an approach?